# I am having a problems with collections and tuples in Python v 3.3.2

Tags: python, tuples

I am using the namedtuple with the collections.  i am getting this error

```
NameError: name collections is not defined.
```

I am using Python v 3.3.2.  Any help would be very appreciated

**[for Example]** I am getting error on this  line

```
Sale = collection.namedtuple("Sale","productid custerid date price")
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you import `collections` module? The module name is `collections`, not `collection`.

```
>>> Sale = collection.namedtuple("Sale","productid custerid date price")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'collection' is not defined
>>>
>>> import collection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named collection
>>>
>>> import collections
>>> Sale = collections.namedtuple("Sale","productid custerid date price")
```